# Why this method currying can run in such a way

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have confused about the code below. Why this can run? And what is the meaning of the `.isEmpty`. In the process of calling `test`, and I am mysterious about the `{` means what? A new Function?

```
def test(age:Int)(name:name_class => name_class): String = {
  val str: String = name.toString()+age+""
  print(str)
  str
}
test(19){
  x =>
    name_class("dage1")
}.isEmpty
```

Answer (score 3):

- `def test` - `test` is a method.
- `(age:Int)` - It takes an `Int` parameter. We'll call it `age`.
- `(name:name_class => name_class)` - It takes a 2nd parameter (curried) that is a function that takes a `name_class` and returns a `name_class`. We'll call that function `name`.
- `: String` - Method `test` returns a `String`.

...

- `test(19)` - Let's invoke the `test` method. The 1st argument, `age`, will be 19.
- `{` - The 2nd argument to `test` starts here. It might be multiple lines of code so we'll use `{...}` instead of `(...)`. (Actually not needed in this case.)
- `x=>` - This is a function that takes a `name_class`. We'll call it `x`. (And ignore it hereafter.)
- `name_class("dage1")` - Return a `name_class`.
- `}` - All done with the 2nd argument to `test`.
- `.isEmpty` - Test the `String` that `test` returns to see if it is empty.